# How to redirect if a method is missing CakePHP?

Tags: php, redirect, cakephp

I have a trouble when I'm using a wrong method with CakePHP and since new versions of it, things have changed. I didn't found how to redirect a wrong page to the default page each time it's a wrong URL.

[image: Here it's the problem]

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and say what results you get, including any errors or messages. Few people will help you without a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use:
$this->redirect(
        array(
              "controller" => "Controller", 
              "action" => "user",
              "?" => array(
                  "username" => "USER123",
                  "usertype" => "Test"
              ) ),
        $status,
        $exit
    );